# Possible for Apps Script to extract the "Before" value of edited cells in specified column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-appsheet

I created an AppSheet app that uses a Google Sheet as its' backend database. When adding new rows through the app, most fields contain text input, except columns E and F, in which users capture images with their mobile device's camera (The photos are visible in the app, but in the Google Sheet they are just a text value describing the path to the image file).

My issue is that the cell values for columns E and F often disappear from random rows in the Google Sheet. Most often the problem occurs hours or days after the affected rows were created. The issue can't be reproduced on-demand, and the only cell values that disappear are cells containing text describing an image file path. This Google Sheet does not use any formulas or scripts.

When comparing the Edit History timestamps of affected cells and other cells in the same row, the "disappeared value" timestamp always matches an edit timestamp for another column value that was updated.  I haven't found any pattern, as each "disappeared value" timestamp matches an edit timestamp for up to 12 different columns. Also, sometimes the "disappeared value" timestamp matches the timestamp for when the row was created (before any columns were updated through AppSheet). Since all row adds and edits are made through the app, I believed it was an AppSheet bug and I opened a support ticket.

AppSheet Tech Support could not identify anything in my app configuration that would cause the issue and their audit logs do not show that any values were deleted from the affected columns, so the issue must be occurring in Google Sheets. When searching for answers through the Google Workspace Admin Console, it appears to be a known issue:

**"Description: In very rare circumstances, a cell's data may disappear from the current version of a sheet.
Workaround: You can recover the missing data by viewing the cell's edit history"**

It would be tedious to copy/paste the deleted value from the affected cells' Edit History multiple times per day, so I'm looking to create a workaround for this known issue. When the value of columns E and F is edited, I'd like to know if it's possible for Apps Script to capture the "Before Edit" value and add it to a new row in a different Google Sheet? If the "Before" values are captured in another sheet, then I can have Appsheet look to the image file path from there when the value of columns E and F are null in the primary sheet.

Comment: It only captures the oldValue of the edited cell. And it only captures manual edits.  I might consider building a new spreadsheet from  a fresh file.

Comment: `In very rare circumstances...` The problem that you have described is not rare - you use `often` to describe frequency. Also the Google issue suggests/implies `unpredictability` but you are experiencing repeated loss of data in two specific columns. I do agree that it would be tedious to copy/paste the deleted value from the affected cells' Edit History. My thought is 1) it's a coding problem. But 2) I'd be archiving the relevant sheet/data regularly so you _should_ have a copy of the original data. 3) a time-driven utility could compare "live" Vs "archived" data to identify lost data.

Comment: @Tedinoz I attempted to make a workaround to the G-sheet issue with an AppSheet automation: When a new row is added through the app, the automation copies the row and adds it to another sheet. When the unwanted behavior occurs and the cell values are lost, the copied values are still present on the workaround sheet, so for the most part, it has worked. Rows that are still problematic are ones in which the values disappear immediately upon the row's creation because the values are already gone when my workaround automation is triggered. Any suggestions on how to handle these rows?

Comment: Does the original app: #1) add a single row or multiple rows on execution? #2) `append` or `insert rows`? #3) `append`, `setValues from a range`, `setValues from an array` (or something else)? 4#) rewrite the entire sheet or just add new data to the sheet? I would try to archive the data BEFORE the execution of the original app, not afterwards.

Comment: @Tedinoz I have no formal training in CS or any related field and am just figuring things out as I go, so I didn't fully understand your questions but will answer to the best of my abilities. The original app can only add one row at a time on execution, and the new rows are appended vs.inserted. The app adds new data to the sheet vs. rewriting the entire sheet. The part you lost me on is "setValues from a range, setValues from an array" (I'm unsure of the difference between the two).

Comment: `one row at a time [...] appended` So the original app shouldn't touch _any_ existing data (unless it's a Google Form response). `I'm unsure of the difference between the two` - don't worry about that for time being. Lindsey, other than saying "shit happens" (which is hardly helpful), we've reached the point (I think) where you're going to have to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  of your scenario, system, scripts and data. Cause we're just working in the dark.